# How to send email when a link is clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

In my iPhone application I had an email address.  If anyone touches touches that link an email should send to that email address.  Is there any way for doing this?

Anyone please help..

Comment: How do you want the email to be sent, mailto or ajax?

Comment: I am doing it in objective C.  I am new to programming. What should I use?

Comment: Do you want the email to be secret or for the user to approve the email? If you want it secret, you could setup a webserver in PHP with a form and the application sends a message to the server which then sends the email (app > server > mail ; relay kind). If you're looking for the user to approve the message use MFMailComposerFrame which is basically a compose-mail thing like in Mail.app.
If you want an explanation for the PHP method tell me and I will show an example.
PS: the PHP method requires you to have either a free or payed server (I use 000webhost.com which is free and supports PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Link is as UIButton ,you may use MFMailComposerFrame Work,related sample code
is in [Apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button with email id as label. 
Use UIApplication's openURL method to send a mail.